# hive rolling average when some days missing

Tags: hive, moving-average

I am working with hive on  huge dataset and trying rolling average for past one week. If data for one day is missing we want to consider rolling average with 6 days.
Self joins are taking a long time so tried window functionality.

e.g.

```
Select date,avg(volume) over (order by date ROWS between 6 preceding AND current row) as Moving_AVG
From job_history;
```

Anyway this can be done with hive window functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Range between 6 preceding and current row`

---

```
select      date
           ,volume
           ,avg (volume) over 
            (   
                order by    date
                range       between 6 preceding and current row
            ) as moving_avg 
            
from        job_history
;
```

---

#### Demo

```
create table job_history (date date,volume int);

insert into job_history values 
    ('2017-01-01', 1),('2017-01-02', 2),('2017-01-05', 3),('2017-01-06', 4),('2017-01-08', 5)
   ,('2017-01-09', 6),('2017-01-10', 7),('2017-01-10', 8),('2017-01-10', 9),('2017-01-11',10)
   ,('2017-01-11',11),('2017-01-12',12),('2017-01-13',13),('2017-01-14',14),('2017-01-17',15)
;   

select * from job_history
;
```

---

```
+------------------+--------------------+
| job_history.date | job_history.volume |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-01       | 1                  |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-02       | 2                  |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-05       | 3                  |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-06       | 4                  |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-08       | 5                  |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-09       | 6                  |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-10       | 7                  |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-10       | 8                  |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-10       | 9                  |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-11       | 10                 |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-11       | 11                 |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-12       | 12                 |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-13       | 13                 |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-14       | 14                 |
+------------------+--------------------+
| 2017-01-17       | 15                 |
+------------------+--------------------+
```

---

```
select      date
           ,volume
           ,avg (volume) over 
            (   
                order by    date
                range       between 6 preceding and current row
            ) as moving_avg 
            
from        job_history
;
```

---

```
+------------+--------+------------+
| date       | volume | moving_avg |
+------------+--------+------------+
| 2017-01-01 | 1      | 1.0        |
+------------+--------+------------+
| 2017-01-02 | 2      | 1.5        |
+------------+--------+------------+
| 2017-01-05 | 3      | 2.0        |
+------------+--------+------------+
| 2017-01-06 | 4      | 2.5        |
+------------+--------+------------+
| 2017-01-08 | 5      | 3.5        |
+------------+--------+------------+
| 2017-01-09 | 6      | 4.5        |
+------------+--------+------------+
| 2017-01-10 | 8      | 6.0        |
+------------+--------+------------+
| 2017-01-10 | 9      | 6.0        |
+------------+--------+------------+
| 2017-01-10 | 7      | 6.0        |
+------------+--------+------------+
| 2017-01-11 | 10     | 7.0        |
+------------+--------+------------+
| 2017-01-11 | 11     | 7.0        |
+------------+--------+------------+
| 2017-01-12 | 12     | 8.0        |
+------------+--------+------------+
| 2017-01-13 | 13     | 9.0        |
+------------+--------+------------+
| 2017-01-14 | 14     | 9.5        |
+------------+--------+------------+
| 2017-01-17 | 15     | 12.5       |
+------------+--------+------------+
```

Comment: so this goes by rows, 6 previous rows. What i am interested is in by 6 days. In your solution if we have a day missing we would have issues. I would like to consider missing day as "0"

Comment: **(1)** No, This goes by range of 6 days, not rows, therefore the `Range between` and not `Rows between`. **You can verify it by looking at the data sample In my answer**  **(2)** If you want `0` for missing days, replace the `avg(...) over (...)` with `sum` and divide by 6

Answer (score 0):

As David mentioned above, you can use range between. However, there is no **INTERVAL** function. Instead we can transfer date to ts first.

```
    AVG(metric) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY author_id
    ORDER BY unix_timestamp(to_date(date))
    RANGE BETWEEN 604800 PRECEDING AND 86400 PRECEDING
         ) AS metric_rolling_7_day_average
```